# Macbook pro 2009 2.66 samsung SSD 830 won't boot internally

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I'm trying to install a Samsung 830 GB in a MacBook Pro 2.66 (2009). It boots and works perfectly external using USB (im using it now) but not internally, so I was wondering what I have to do to make things working.
I'm running mountain lion 10.8.2

I've searched this issue on Google but no one has come up with a definitive answer

Comment: How did you prepare the drive? GUID partition scheme with Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and a clean install? Or CCC right on to the drive externally? This may have something to do with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I afraid you might be in for a struggle having done this upgrade on a mid-2009 15" MacBook Pro and I'm not alone in having the problem. I ended up having to replace the drive cable and switch to using an SATA2 rather than SATA3 drive to get an replacement drive (SSD or magnetic) to work. The problem is documented on the OWC web site.

As I recall, I got a larger replacement magnetic drive to work by downgrading the firmware but getting an SSD to work required upgrading to firmware, replacing the cable, and getting an SATA2 drive. If you already have the drive, start with the cable and maybe that will be good enough.

I've cloned lots of drives to external drives and then swapped in the external drive for the internal without a problem so I think it's far more likely you have the hardware compatibility problem than a software issue.

BTW, even with a SATA2 drive, the upgraded system flies.

Answer (score 0):

Okay while pending an answer on my comment on the question, im going to venture a "pre answer" if you will.

Seems like if you CCC'd to the new drive externally there will be an issue with Lion/MLion's Recovery partition and will cause either the mount paths to be screwy, or the drive size to become incorrect.

[This forum post seems to highlight a similar issue although different hardware.](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1238241)

The OP of the linked thread fixed his issue by connecting his old HDD externally, and inserting the new drive internally and then CCC'ing that way. It seems like what this does is solve the Mount path issues and allows the Recovery drive to be cloned properly.

Good luck! I will edit if necessary!